# IntelliJ showing invalid HTML warning - sources taken from different module

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, node-modules

I have a quite large project with different frontends based on different angular/bootstrap versions. The frontends are Maven modules and each one is a separate IDEA module, each has its own subfolder.

```
parent
+ frontend1
| + src
| + node_modules
|   + bootstrap
|   ...
|
+ frontend2
| + src
| + node_modules
|   + bootstrap
|   ...
```

When I open a html file from frontend2, which uses a higher version of bootstrap, IntelliJ (2018.1.8 and 2018.2.2) displays a "unknown html tag" warning. 
Navigating to a known tag via ctrl+click jumps to the `node_modules/bootstrap` folder of frontend1.

This seem very weird to me. I've already tried `File -> Invalidate Caches` and also defining `frontend2/node_modules` as resource for module frontend2, but with no effect.

Has anyone similar effects or a solution to this problem?

Comment: are `frontend1` and `frontend2` different IDEA modules, or the same one? Sample project that shows up the issue would be helpful

Comment: Created a demo project. Get it at https://www.pastefs.com/pid/71275. The frontends are separate IDEA modules.

Comment: thanks, reproduced. I've created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34582, please follow it for updates